# Dropzonejs object object error. How can I fix it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, dropzone.js, dropzone

**Files can't be upload to directory and give back error**

js and css from dropzone is included in head and footer properly

[image: Display on blade]

[image: Network]

[image: Dropzone js code]

[image]

[image]

Balde code::

```
@include('Templates.head')
<body style="background: #283747;">
    @include('Menu.menu')
    @if (Session::has('user') && Session::has('privlages') && Session::get('privlages') >= '1')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="/gallery_add_image" class="dropzone" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;">
                @csrf
                <div class="fallback">
                  <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @else
    <script>window.location = "/";</script>
    @endif
@include('Templates.footer')
```

Controller code::

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GalerryController extends Controller
{
    public function add_image(Request $add_image){
        $image = $add_image->file('file');
        $imageName = time(). '.' . $add_image->extension();
        $image->move(public_path('gallery'), $imageName);
        return response()->json(['success' => $imageName]);
    }
}
```

web(routing) code::

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\GalerryController;

Route::post('/gallery_add_image', [GalerryController::class, 'add_image']);
```

Server response code::

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check the network tab for the actual error.

Comment: I checked and add image.

Comment: Click on one of the red "gallery_add_image" lines, then click either `Preview` or `Response` to see what the server is sending back.

Comment: You need to CLICK on one of the red lines and THEN click on response to check for server response. https://prnt.sc/1rdp9n0 otherwise, check your log file for the nature of the 500 error

Comment: Okay now added but i can't see anything what can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller code `$add_image` is a request object, which does not have an `extension` method. To get the uploaded file extension you need to use:

```php
class GalerryController extends Controller
{
    public function add_image(Request $add_image) {
        $add_image->validate([ 'file' => 'required|image' ]); // Good idea to validate
        $image = $add_image->file('file');
        $imageName = time(). '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('gallery'), $imageName);
        return response()->json(['success' => $imageName]);
    }
}
```